# What happens to Iskahn and Sheyta?

Tags: sword-art-online

In Chapter 21 of Alicization,

> when Sheyta's sword breaks, it appears they are doomed as the red army closes in.

However,

> Leafa comes to save them with the orcs. When she kills everyone and collapses from exhaustion, no other mention of Iskahn (and Sheyta) that I know of appears in the rest of Volume 17 and Volume 18.

What happens to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear in

> Moon Cradle, the sun-arc after Alicization.

I haven't read the arc personally but from looking at illustrations,

> they help out zkititi within the story. Also, they have a baby.